# First passage time in a renewal reward process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stopping-times, poisson-process, renewal-processes

Let $$Y(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{N(t)} X_n e^{-\alpha(t-T_n)}$$

be a renewal-reward process such that $X_n\sim \Gamma(2,1)$ and the arrival times $T_n$ correspond to a Poisson process of rate $1$ whose occurrences are counted in $N(t)$.

I understand this is a standard renewal-reward process [as defined in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewal_theory#Renewal-reward_processes), where the rewards depend on the arrival times.

I am interested in calculating the expected first passage time (i.e. the first instant in which $Y(t)$ exceeds some constant $K$). Namely, the expected value of $$T_K = \inf\{t\,:\, Y(t) >K \}$$

Is there a closed form for this expression, given the complexity of the process? I know that $\mathbb{P}(T_K\geq t)=\mathbb{P}(Y(t)<K)$, but the density of $Y(t)$ seems to be something quite difficult to integrate in order to find a closed form for $\mathbb{E}[T_K]$.

Any ideas or any sources I could use to know how to proceed?

Comment: By $X_n\sim\Gamma(2,1)$ do you mean that the density is $xe^{-x}$ or $2e^{-2x}$?

Comment: Also, are the $X_n$ assumed to be independent of the $T_n$?

Comment: @Math1000 Yes, $X_n$ are $T_n$ are independent. The density of the $X_n$ is $xe^{-x}$.